# xslt ss:formula works in xls but not in xlsx

Tags: .net, xslt

I am systematically generating a xls file using xslt formatting.
However, I am having difficulty having the formula generating for .xlsx format.
Short description is that I'm connecting to a stored procedure that provides the data elements for the excel spreadheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  exclude-result-prefixes="o x ss">


  <Cell ss:StyleID="Number2Dec">
    <Data ss:Type="Number">
      <xsl:value-of select="AmountDue" />
    </Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="Number2Dec">
    <Data ss:Type="Number">
      <xsl:value-of select="AmountRecovered" />
    </Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="Number2Dec" ss:Formula="=SUM(RC[-2]-RC[-1])">
    <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
  </Cell>
```

When it generates in .xls format, the formula calculates properly, no issues there.
However when I generate in .xlsx format, it just displays a 0 in the column.
I have a .cs program that will calculate it out as below

```
if (cellNode.Attributes != null && cellNode.Attributes["ss:Formula"] != null)
{
  var formula = cellNode.Attributes["ss:Formula"].Value;
if (formula.StartsWith("RC"))
  cell.FormulaR1C1 = formula;
else
  cell.FormulaA1 = formula;
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am able to get it going in .xlsx but now it doesn't work in .xls.  
Changing the .cs to a " if (formula.Contains("RC"))"  
then adjusted the report .xslt to be        
<Cell ss:StyleID="Number2Dec" ss:Formula="=SUM(RC[-3]:RC[-1])">
  <Data ss:Type="">0</Data>
</Cell>

Comment: Now changed the type to the following and it works ...  <Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data>